# What are some properties or characteristics of singular eigenvector matrices?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, singularity-theory

I'm trying to predict when a matrix $A$ will have an eigenvector matrix $X$ that is singular. What properties or characteristics would $A$ or $X$ have to make $X$ singular??

Answer (score 3):

A square matrix $A$ can only have a *non-singular* eigenvector matrix if $A$ is [diagonalizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix).

Strictly speaking, every matrix size $2$ and bigger has **a** singular "eigenvector matrix".

**EDIT:** to your comment: if we have an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ whose eigenvalues are $\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k\}$, where this list repeats no eigenvalues, then $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if
$$
(A - \lambda_1 I)(A - \lambda_2 I)\cdots(A - \lambda_k I) = 0
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.  This uses the idea of a matrix's [minimal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29).

Comment: Yes, but what is it about $A$ that makes it diagonalizable? If I have two matrices, how can I tell without performing computations that one is diagonalizable and the other isn't?

Comment: See my latest edit.  You have to perform *some* computation, but not as much as you might think.

Comment: This is difficult to tell in practice since the eigenvector matrix could have an awful condition number.

Comment: If I may criticize, your edit does not seem useful since it only covers the special case when the eigenvalues are distinct.

Comment: @JessicaK you misunderstand: if an eigenvalue repeats, you only list it once.  If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, this list might not be $n$ entries long.  In fact, if $A$ does have $n$ distinct eigenvalues, it will be diagonalizable, and so the product will be zero.

Comment: Ah I see, trying to avoid speaking of the minimal polynomial made the statement a little confusing. Sorry!

Comment: @Peter Another factor that makes this difficult is that different eigenvalues can be very close together, but distinct.

Comment: @Peter from the phrase "singular eigenvalue matrix", I assumed you were more interested in computational aspects of diagonalization.  However, if you are interested in seeing more of the theory, I suggest reading up on [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).